# Jquery if checked toggle class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a box with a checkbox, I want to insert in jQuery if the checkbox is checked toggle the class on the box with a `transition`, but it fails and below is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($('.onoffcheck').is(':checked')) {
    $(".panel-success").toggleClass("panel-off2");
  } else {
          $(".panel-off").toggleClass("panel-success");
}
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z68SF/)

Comment: missed to add jQuery lib in fiddle(left topmost in the fiddle).. Also I dont see any event listener..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.onoffcheck').change(function () {
        $("#node2").toggleClass("panel-off2", this.checked).toggleClass("panel-success", !this.checked);
    }).change()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/F4B3q/)

Comment: what is the `panel-off` and `panel-off2` classes

Comment: In my website (i have it in local) the code that works in jsfiddle doesn't work because my checkbox is hidded and modified with jquery to make this: http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/ How can i do?

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga try `$('.onoffcheck').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function () {...`

Comment: Works perfect now!! Only one thing more, how can make a smooth transition with css in the changing class and change the square to be green when checked and grey when not checked glyphicon class glyphicon-stop off (grey) and class glyphicon glyphicon-stop on (green)

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga which square

Comment: this class:   <div class="panel-heading"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop off"></span>  Node 1 </div> (class glyphicon glyphicon-stop off)

Comment: Where is the CSS in your last fiddle? And the code that makes the square appear green or not, i don't see.. and i want to make css transitions with the changes to look smother

Answer (score 1):

First make sure to include the jQuery library.
Then you have to listen to the checkbox change event. Otherwise the conditional check gets only executed on document ready.

E.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.onoffcheck').on('change', function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(".panel-success").toggleClass("panel-off2");
        } else {
            $(".panel-off").toggleClass("panel-success");
        }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z68SF/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a `change` listener to make the `toggle` logic execute on every `checked` change. See [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/z68SF/2/)

```
var toggle = function () {
    if ($('.onoffcheck').is(':checked')) {
        $(".panel-success").toggleClass("panel-off2");
    } else {
        $(".panel-off").toggleClass("panel-success");
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    toggle();  // initial execution
    $('.onoffcheck').on('change', toggle); // execute it on every change
});
```